# signed up in 2010-now trying to access

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts

Back when I signed up with bitcoin and received 2 bitcoins, I haven't done anything with my account/wallet since 2010 is there a way for me to access my bitcoins or have they been lost, I still have the same email address, thanks

Comment: What does "I signed up with Bitcoin" mean? Did you run some program? Did you go to some web site?

Answer (score 1):

IF you still have your wallet:

1. This means you still have your private key
2. This also means you have your public key (you call it the same email address i assume)
3. syncronize the blockchain on your bitcoin client in case of using bitcoin-qt. This will take some time (+-2 days)
4. Copy your public key and go to [blockchain website](https://blockchain.info/) and past you key in the search bar. This will show you if the bitcoins still exist.
5. In case they still exist on the blockchain then once the blockchain has been syncronized and completed it will also appear in your wallet.

If you lost your wallet and you never wrote your private and public key down then they are lost for ever!

Comment: okay went to the login location and filled out info on lost both wallet/key and all I had was my email address and it wouldnt accept--saying "invalid GUID"  I don't know what that means? I can't remember my passphrase but if I knew what kind of response -I do have my old tower from back then--but hate to dig that out and search if the coins are lost thanks so much

Comment: What wallet did you originally use?

Comment: I cant remember any of it -I think it was about day-2 of them being available, before this whole sub-language developed, whatever I did would have been the first version of everything, I looked for what GUI means -couldnt find that so i cant even enter my request to look for my old data.

Comment: If you downloaded the Bitcoin client, you would have a "wallet.dat" file somewhere with the keys in it. It would help a lot if you described the process in as much detail as you can remember. What did you need your email address for?